# Catch data from DataTable in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, sql-server-2012, command

```
SqlCommand detailsCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT bd.bookName, bd.authorName, bd.publishDate bc.description, bd.keyWords FROM bookCart as bc, bookDetails as bd WHERE bc.bookCode = bd.code");

DataTable detailsTable = book.showData(detailsCommand);

String BookName = detailsTable.Rows[0]["bookName"].ToString();
String AuthorName = detailsTable.Rows[1]["authorName"].ToString();
String PublishDate = detailsTable.Rows[2]["publishDate"].ToString();
String Describe = detailsTable.Rows[3]["describtion"].ToString();
String KeyWords = detailsTable.Rows[4]["keyWords"].ToString();
```

It gives me an `IndexOutOfRangeException` in the last two lines.

I guess it's because the describe is in another table, but I could not solve it, can you help me with this please?

Comment: I see several problems. 1. the field name `describtion` is spelt incorrectly. 2. There is a missing comma (`,`) between publishDate and description in the `SELECT` statement. 3. You are looking at 5 different rows for one record.

Comment: are you sure you want to read each column from different rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next:

```
String BookName = detailsTable.Rows[0]["bookName"].ToString();
String AuthorName = detailsTable.Rows[0]["authorName"].ToString();
String PublishDate = detailsTable.Rows[0]["publishDate"].ToString();
String Describe = detailsTable.Rows[0]["description"].ToString();
String KeyWords = detailsTable.Rows[0]["keyWords"].ToString();
```

[`DataTable.Rows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rows?view=netcore-3.1) contains the collection of rows that belong to this table, so `detailsTable.Rows[0]` is a first row, `detailsTable.Rows[1]` is second one and so on (in your case it seems there are 3 of them, so you get [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f) on 4th one)